# Capturing outgoing discord bot requests via Linux

Tags: linux, debian, logging, http

What i would like to do is somehow to capture the outgoing requests of my discord bots to discord with full description of the requests
path, get / post etc..
Couldn't find any way to do it properly,
Running Debian

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your bots to (temporarily) use a proxy server like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) which will record all of the requests and allow you to view/save them.